# .htacces: преобразование ссылки

Tags: .htaccess, преобразование, ссылки

Прошу помощи! 
Имеются пути с картинками вида

```
http://сайт.com/assets/components/gallery/connector.php?action=web/phpthumb&ctx=web&w=750&h=800&zc=0&far=&q=90&src=%2Fassets%2Fgallery%2F30%2F624.jpg
```

где цифра 30 - это альбом с фото под названием, например,  Отопление.
Требуется, чтобы отображался путь

```
http://сайт.com/gallery/otoplenie/624.jpg
```

Возможно ли такое? Укажите, где почитать по такому преобразованию.
P.S. Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Почитать на http://www.htaccess.net.ru/
Из вопроса не ясно, чему должны быть равны остальные пареметры типа w, h, zc, far, q и т.п.

**Обновление**

Как-то так должно быть, я думаю. Для каждого otoplenie пишешь свою строку `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^gallery/otoplenie/(\d+).jpg http://сайт.com/assets/components/gallery/connector.php?action=web/phpthumb&ctx=web&w=750&h=800&zc=0&far=&q=90&src=%2Fassets%2Fgallery%2F30%2F$1.jpg
```

Comment: Спс за ссылку. Остальные параметры остаются неизменные. Т.е. так как в данном примере, меняется только каталог и имя изображения

Comment: Обновил ответ